# HTML Tidy removes comments with conditions

Tags: php, html, tidy

I am making use of [HTML tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) and I've had a look at the [config options here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#preserve-entities).

I've made use of this option:

```
$config = array(
                'hide-comments' => 1
                );
```

However, it removes comments such as this:

```
<!-- Test -->
```

and this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>Special instructions for IE 6 here<![endif]-->
```

Should it be removing the latter, I know its still a comment but it serves a purpose - maybe I should use another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no option for it.. After all it is a HTML comment. I would recommend you find an alternative, or keep the HTML comments.. They can't be that heavy.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other option to remove comments like this, because they are browser-dependent.

HTML Tidy is not recognizing content of comment, it just removes it by something similar to regexp rule.

This behavior is a feature, not a bug.

Info:
http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2811312&group_id=27659&atid=451767
[HTML Tidy, Don't move those comments!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537112/html-tidy-dont-move-those-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Pretty Diff.  It is a more complete algorithm than Tidy and it does not remove your comments or make assumptions about the completeness of your input.

http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation.

Comment: Pretty Diff is not better than Tidy, it's just a GUI. BTW, how would you modify 10.000 html files from this tool? Copying and pasting the html code 10.000 times? Tidy is a command line tool that can do a task recursively, even for a milion files, with only one command.